# Bootstrap5 Carousel: How to Move Icons

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootsrap5's carousel and here is the picture.

[image]

As you can see the prev and next icons overlap with the text.  I would like to move them, if possible, to a  just above the upvote/downvote buttons.  Yet, they seem to render inside the class="inner carousel" regardless of where I put the code related to the icons.  I read the W3C write-up and I have seen many posts on Stack Overflow stating that is hard to change the formatting for the carousel, but if anyone has ideas, please provide.

Here is my code.

```
       <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <!-- data-bs-ride="carousel" excluded -->
            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" >
      
              <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="row" id = "message-body">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center">Use Left and Right Arrows </h1>
                    <h1 style="text-align: center">to Scroll</h1>
                    <h1 style="text-align: center">Through Questions</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <%   
                var max = questions.length
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                  relevance = questions[i].upvotes
                %>
              <div class="carousel-item" style="text-align: justify" >
                <div class="row" id = "message-body">
                  <h2><%= questions[i].title %></h2>
                  <p><%= questions[i].body %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <p><strong>Posted by: </strong><%= questions[i].userid.username %> on <%= questions[i].datePosted.toDateString() %> </p>
                  <p id= "questionID"> type="number"><%= questions[i]._id %></p>
                  <script>$("#questionID").hide(); </script>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% } %>          
            <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->  
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Blank Row -->
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center"></div>
            <!-- Upvote and Downvote Buttons -->
            <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
              <div class="text-center" style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;"> 
                <button style = "display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 50%; border:2px solid black; border-radius: 10px; background-color: none; margin-left:20px" id="minus"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
                  <p id = "score" type="number" class="text-center" style = "display: inline-block; text-align: centered; width: 50%; height: 40%;"> <%= relevance %> </p>
                <button style = "display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 50%; border-radius: 10px; border:2px solid black; background-color: none" id="plus"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
              </div>
              <div class="row" >
                <button id="submitButton" style = "border-radius: 8px; margin-left: 20px; background-color:darkcyan; width: 200px; margin-bottom:15px" type="submit">View Responses</button>
              </div>
            </div>              
          </div>              
        </div>
```

Comment: There have bee [many questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=move+bootstrap+carousel+controls+outside+site:stackoverflow.com) on this already. The solutions are always the same: negative margins, X-axis translation, absolute positioning, etc.

Comment: OK.  I didn't see one for a separate div, but if I can't find anything I will use the negative margins.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Your code example is not optimized for discussion here (see [ask]), so I didn't look very closely at it.

Comment: My point is that you _really_ want to get away from inline styles. It's very hard to work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons can easily be shifted with X-axis translation.

```css
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  transform: translateX(60px);
  background: red;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  transform: translateX(-60px);
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control-next-icon {
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-control-next-icon {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-control-next-icon {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
  .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    transform: translateX(-120px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>

        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```